# Power series of $\frac{1}{7+x}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

For my calculus 2 class, I was given the problem to solve for the power series of $\frac{1}{7+x}$. For my solution, I said $\frac{1}{7+x} = -\frac{1}{1 - (8 + x)}$ and used $8 + x$ as $r$ and $-1$ as $a$ to get $-(8 + x)^n$. It turned out the solution was $\frac{(-x)^n}{7^{(n + 1)}}$. Why was I wrong?

Comment: It may be the answer was going for a power series centered at $x=0$ but yours is not,

Answer (score 4):

A power series* has the form
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots$$
for some coefficients $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots$.  Yours looks like this:
$$\frac{1}{7+x} = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty (8+x)^k = -1 - (8+x) - (8+x)^2 - \cdots$$
It doesn't fit the form specified in the first equation because $(8+x)^k$ is not of the form $x^k$.
The given solution is
$$\frac{1}{7+x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{7^{k+1}} x^k = \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{49} x + \frac{1}{343} x^2 - \cdots.$$
And here we can say that $$a_0 = \frac{1}{7}, \quad a_1 = -\frac{1}{49}, \quad a_2 = \frac{1}{343}, \ldots.$$

This brings to mind the question of whether you could expand the terms in your series to write it this way.  For instance,
$$(8+x)^2 = 64+16x+x^2.$$
Could we collect the like terms?  The answer is no:  the constant term, which is the first term, is
$$-1-8-8^2-8^3-8^4-\cdots,$$
which does not converge to a finite value.  Does this mean your computation is wrong?  Also, no.  It is correct, but it doesn't behave like the series given in the solution, since for that series, if we plug in $x = 0$, we would have $1/7$.  But if we plug in $0$ for your series, you would get $-\infty$.  On the other hand, if we plugged in $x = -8$, your series works:  $$\frac{1}{7+(-8)} = -1 = -1 - (8-8) - (8-8)^2 - \cdots.$$
And $x = -8$ does not work for the series in the solution, since
$$\frac{(-1)^k}{7^{k+1}} 8^k = \frac{1}{7} \left(-\frac{8}{7}\right)^k,$$ and this would give you terms with alternating sign, but strictly increasing magnitude, and the series does not converge for this value.

So, while we can say that your result is **a** series, it is not a "power series" in the sense that it is not centered at $x = 0$.  Some mathematicians would say that a "power series" is "centered at $c$" if it has the form
$$f_c(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (x-c)^k = a_0 + a_1 (x-c) + a_2 (x-c)^2 + \cdots,$$
and in this case, your series fits this form with the choice $c = -8$.  But when the center is not specified, it is implied to be zero.  Some mathematicians call such a series "Taylor series" when $c \ne 0$ and a "Maclaurin series" when $c = 0$.

The other point I should make here is that your choice of expansion is not unique.  You could have written, for instance,
$$\frac{1}{7+x} = -\frac{1}{2-(9+x)} = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{9+x}{2}} = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\tfrac{9+x}{2})^k.$$  As such, when we say "power series" in this context, we really mean "power series centered at $x = 0$," since such a series is unique.

Answer (score 3):

To get the given solution, write the function as $$\frac1{7+x}=\frac17\frac1{1+\frac x7}$$Your formula also works, but as a commenter stated, the power series isn't centered around the same point.